# Flask-Admin: how to show all fields

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Well I have different collections (i.e. tables), and they have different columns, say collection **A** has cols a1 and a2, collection **B** has b1 and b2. I want to show all columns

tried following

```
class UserView(ModelView):
    column_list = None
```

also

```
column_exclude_list = None
```

getting

```
NotImplementedError
```

how can I display all fields?

I mean

```
column_list = ('a1','a2','b1','b2')
```

works, but I do not want to see empty b1 and b2 fields when looking collection A.

Answer (score 2):

In Flask-Admin one class inheriting ModelView normally represents one SQLAlchemy model. You can show columns of multiple tables in one view if they are connected via relationship or hybrid property. ModelView serves primarily to add basic CRUD operations to your models.

So in your case your should have two classes and two views

```
class AView(ModelView):
    column_list('a1', 'a2')      #also if you don't add the column list           
                                 #property, all columns except primary key will be shown

class BView(ModelView):
    column_list('b1','b2')


app.add_view(AView(db.session, category='Models'))
app.add_view(BView(db.session, category='Models'))
```

See this example:
http://examples.flask-admin.org/sqla/simple/admin/

Hope this helps.

In case you don't want to explicitly list all columns you define the constructor
as following and all columns in the table (except PK) will be shown

```
class AView(ModelView):

    def __init__(self,session, **kwargs):
        super(AView, self).__init__(ModelName,session,**kwargs)
```

You replace the ModelName with the name of your model class.

Comment: I guess there is a typo there colum_list = ('a1','a2') this works, but in your comment you say if I dont add the column list property all columns should show. You mean writing just class AView(ModelView)? Can you give an example code for that part

Comment: I edited the answer and added an example without column_list property.

Comment: I do not have a model class, I am using pymongo, there is no ODM or ORM.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to achieve this with pymongo.